# Is there any way to build URL in JSP using <spring:url> tag by appending/substitute query parameter in current page URL?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

If, for example, current page URL is *'http://domain.com/page?param1=value1&param2=value2'*, then:

```xml
<spring:url value="">
  <spring:param name="param3" value="value3" />
</spring:url>
```

produces *'http://domain.com/page?param1=value1&param2=value2&**param3=value3**'*, but

```xml
<spring:url value="">
  <spring:param name="param2" value="value3" />
</spring:url>
```

produces *'http://domain.com/page?param1=value1&**param2=value3**'*.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - could you add a little more detail please?

Comment: I just want to include current query string in all links on page, but for some links I want to add additional or substitute existing params.

Comment: So you're trying to change params? I suspect you'd need to build up the query string again, but I'm not an expert so I'm unable to help, sorry

Comment: `<spring:url value=""/>` will just give you the URL to your context root, not your current page.

Comment: I clearly understand this, so I'm trying to find out how to achieve this by using 'url' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thе only solution that comes to my mind is to provide a collection of params and iterate through them ignoring params which must be substituted/ommited:

```xml
<spring:url value="">
  <spring:param name="param3" value="value3" />
  <c:forEach items="additionalParams" var="aParam">
    <c:if test="${aParam.name ne 'param3'}">
      <spring:param name="${aParam.name}" value="${aParam.value}" />
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</spring:url>
```